# What is the numeral system which uses the number of digits as a signifier of value called?

Tags: terminology, recreational-mathematics, number-systems

Our standard notation of representing numbers has an implied infinite number of zero digits on the left of all numbers. 42, 042 and 00000000042 all represent the same number.

I'm thinking of the slightly different notation where the number of digits is significant. The sequence looks like this:
0,1,...,8,9,00,01,...,98,99,000,001,...,998,999,0000,...

The most famous (maybe) example of this system are the spreadsheet columns. These go:
A,B,...,Y,Z,AA,AB,...,ZY,ZZ,AAA,...

Does this style of notation have a name? I'd like to do some casual research on this idea and I need a word I can search for as a starting point.

Bonus question: Do you know of anything interesting I can read on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This order is sometimes called the *[shortlex order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order)*: length first, and lexicographic order for strings of the same length.